# Is there any class to return a print of a function?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sockets

I am developing a python program for reading ports. My script has a print for every open port checked. But I would like to remove this print and put it inside a class. For when the programmer wants to see print he calls the class.

I can create common classes to get user input from a main file (main.py) and run inside the script, but I can't control print from the main file

```py
def ping(target,scale):
    def portscan(port):

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            con = s.connect((target,port))
            time.sleep(5)

            port_print = 'Port :',port,"Is Open!."
            time.sleep(5)
            #python = sys.executable
            #os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
            print('Terminated')
            con.close()

        except:
            #result = None
            #return result
            pass
    r = 1
    scal = int(scale)
    for x in range(1,scal):

        t = threading.Thread(target=portscan,kwargs={'port':r})
        r += 1
        t.start()
```

As you can see I created the variable port_print, and I would like that when the user called in the main file, there would be the print.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Queue`to get around `return` limitations in threads:

```
from queue import Queue

def ping(target,scale, queue):
    def portscan(port, queue):

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            con = s.connect((target,port))
            time.sleep(5)

            port_print = 'Port :',port,"Is Open!."
            queue.put(port_print)
            time.sleep(5)
            #python = sys.executable
            #os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
            print('Terminated')
            con.close()

        except:
            #result = None
            #return result
            pass
    r = 1
    scal = int(scale)
    for x in range(1,scal):

        t = threading.Thread(target=portscan,kwargs={'port':r, queue=queue})
        r += 1
        t.start()

def main():
    my_queue = Queue()
    target = 'some target'
    scale = 10
    ping(target, scale, my_queue)
    random_port_print = my_queue.get()
    print(random_port_print)
```

> Not tested but prly pretty close to correct.